# Open a case-sensitive URL in iOS

Tags: ios, url, case-sensitive

I was trying to use [UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL: url] to open a url, it could launch safari, but seems url is converted to lower-case, but my url is a case-sensitive.
does anyone point me a direction how to handle this url with case-sensitive ?

here is a example url: ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/standards/RFC/rfc959.txt.
after safari is launched, this url is converted to ftp://ftp.funet.fi/pub/standards/rfc/rfc959.txt .

thanks in advance.

Comment: I tested this using Apple's [LaunchMe](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LaunchMe/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007417) sample project, altering the URL Safari launches to your example URL (see `RootViewController -startMobileSafari:`). It works fine, case-sensitivy is retained. Your issue must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks Jay. you are right. after reading your comments, I carefully go through all my code, finally I managed to find that my URL is converted into lower case before I got it and then called openURL on UIApplication.